# MVC Razor get option value from select with FormCollection

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, select, razor, formcollection

My view has a Select with elements(options) from my ViewModel.

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("NewUser", "Admin"))
        {
             <select multiple="" id="inputRole" class="form-control" size="6" name="inputRole">
             @foreach (var item in Model.roller)
             {
                 <option>@item.Name</option>
             }
             </select>
         }
```

How can i get the selected value in my Controller?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewUser(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        String roleValue1 = formCollection.Get("inputRole");
    }
```

This gives me a null value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this to get the value of control in the formcollection

```
formCollection["inputRole"]
```

Your code becomes

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewUser(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        String roleValue1 = formCollection["inputRole"];
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply accesss your form field by its name in that way

```
    String role = formCollection["inputRole"];
```