# How to get checkbox selected value and pass to controller in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to get the selected checkboxes value

this are my models,

```
public class VehicleViewModel : Vehicle
{
    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Type")]
    [Required( ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    public string VehicleTypeName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AssignProductsViewModel> AssignedProducts { get; set; }
}

public class AssignProductsViewModel
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

here's my razor view

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AssignedProducts)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value ="@item.ProductID"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ProductName)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

and here's my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NewVehicle(VehicleViewModel vehicleViewModel, string selected)
{
  //Do something with the string here
  return View();
}
```

I know I need to pass the selected check boxes value to a string using javascript and pass the string to a controller. But i have no idea how to do it since I'm a newbie in javascript and MVC.

Comment: Your checkboxes don't even have a `name` attribute so wont post back. You also creating invalid html with duplicate `id` attributes. Then you would need to make the parameter an array e.g. `string[] selectedCheckboxes` although property `ProductID` suggests its probably `int` anyway. Start by looking at the [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to understand how to post using ajax.

Comment: You always use the FormCollection.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303236/mvc-razor-get-option-value-from-select-with-formcollection

Comment: @TimSouthard , is it applicaple with tables? and i need to be able to check mulitiple checkboxes as posibble. Thanks. :)

Comment: It'll work with any tags as long as you use a form.

Comment: Do not use `FormCollection`. You should always bind to a model and let MVC take care of binding and validation for you. And is there a reason you need to use ajax to post rather than a standard form submit?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i thought of using ajax because i am not sure how to bind my model, but it would be a lot better if there is a way that i will not be using ajax, thanks

Comment: You simply need to use a view model that represents what you want to display/edit. In your case a `boolen` property (say) `IsSelected` that you can bind a checkbox to, and post back the collection.I'll add answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments that an ajax post is not required, your `AssignProductsViewModel` requires an additional property to bind the checkboxes

```
public class AssignProductsViewModel
{
  public long ProductID { get; set; }
  public string ProductName { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; } // add this
}
```

In the view, use a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate` to render the collection do the controls are correctly named with indexers. A `foreach` loop generates duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name` attributes (cannot be bound to a collection)

```
@model VehicleViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  // controls for VehicleTypeName, LocationName
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.AssignedProducts.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AssignedProducts[i].ProductID) // ditto for ProductName if you want it on postback
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AssignedProducts[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AssignedProducts[i].IsSelected, Model.AssignedProducts[i].ProductName)
  }
  ....
}
```

and post back to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NewVehicle(VehicleViewModel model)
{
  // model.AssignedProducts contains the collection with a value indicating if the product has been selected
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an `EditorTemplate` for type of `AssignProductsViewModel` to render the collection

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AssignProductsViewModel.cshtml`

```
@model AssignProductsViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductID) // ditto for ProductName if you want it on postback
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m..IsSelected, Model.ProductName)
```

and in the main view

```
@model VehicleViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  // controls for VehicleTypeName, LocationName
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.AssignedProducts)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but i am having an error on for loop : CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

Comment: Oops, didn't notice your property was `IEnumerable`. It needs to be `IList<AssignProductsViewModel>`. But if you can;t change it, then you can use a custom `EditorTemplate` (I'll update answer to add that option anyway)